# Parsing String into a Calendar object

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I am having trouble parsing a string which contains ONLY the MONTH and DAY information into a date object. Looking through other threads I decided to use SimpleDateFormatter. Here is my code:

```
void checkDay(Calendar now) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(now.getTimeZone());
    for (String holiday : usHolidayList) {
        Date holidayDate = null;
        try {
            holidayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD").parse(holiday);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        checkNotNull(holidayDate);
        cal.setTime(holidayDate);
        if (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) && now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

usHolidayList is like --> "01/01", 05/25" which contains only the MONTH and DAY information. I just need to get 05/25 and transform this to a date. I dont care about the year or time components.

With my current code, the DAY seems to be parsed correctly but the MONTH is always set to January.

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
Sun Jan 25 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

I expected it to be 
    Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
    Sun May 25 00:00:00 UTC 1970

Really appreciate some thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It was the pattern in SimpleDateFormatter
holidayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD").parse(holiday);

Should be:
holidayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(holiday);

DD - day in a year
dd - day in a month (which is what i want)
Since all my dates were within 30, it fell into January I believe